# Youtube API setScheduledStartTime

Tags: java, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

How set timezone to Rome(GMT+2) ?

When I create a Live Broadcast the timezone is automatically set to Pacific.

How set Timezone to Italia (GMT +02:00) Roma ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Rome time to UTC time and use the format  '2017-04-05T00:00:00.000Z'.  The Z at the back means UTC time.